# Iphone AddressBook Framework - Person attributes

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am trying to find out which attributes a complete "Person Record" in the iPhone Addressbook has by default.

It must be hidden somewhere in the API

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/addressbook#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007210

but I didn't find a list so far.

Has anybody a list of the attributes: Name, Prename, email, tel and possible "hidden" field like entry created

Comment: list is at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/addressbook/address_book_objective_c_constants/default_person_properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSAutoreleasePool* pool  = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

NSArray *array= (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

for (id persion in array) 
{
    ABRecordRef record = (ABRecordRef)persion;

    NSString* firstName=(NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    NSString* lastName=(NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

    //do something

    [firstName release];
    [lastName release];


    ABMultiValueRef mulPhone = (ABMultiValueRef) ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonPhoneProperty) ;
    int count = ABMultiValueGetCount(mulPhone);
    for(CFIndex i=0 ; i < count ; i++)
    {
        NSString* phoneLabel = (NSString*) ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(mulPhone, i) ;        
        NSString* cellPhone =(NSString*) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(mulPhone, i) ;

        //do something

        [phoneLabel release] ;
        [cellPhone release];
    }
    CFRelease(mulPhone) ;


    ABMultiValueRef mulAddress =(ABMultiValueRef) ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonAddressProperty) ;
    count = ABMultiValueGetCount(mulAddress);
    for(CFIndex i=0 ; i< count ; i++)
    {
        NSString* addressLabel = (NSString*) ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(mulAddress, i) ;

        CFDictionaryRef dict = (CFDictionaryRef)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(mulAddress, i);

        NSString* homeStreet  = (NSString*)CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressStreetKey);
        NSString* homeCity    = (NSString*)CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressCityKey);
        NSString* homeCountry = (NSString*)CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressCountryKey);

       //do something
        CFRelease(dict) ;

        [addressLabel release];
    }
    CFRelease(mulAddress) ;



    NSString* company  = (NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonOrganizationProperty);
    if (company) {
 //do something
    }
    [company release];



    ABMultiValueRef mulEmail = (ABMultiValueRef)ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonEmailProperty) ;
    count = ABMultiValueGetCount(mulEmail);
    for(CFIndex i=0 ; i<  count; i++)
    {
        NSString* emailLabel = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(mulEmail, i) ;
        NSString* email = (NSString*) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(mulEmail, i) ;

        //do something
        [emailLabel release];
        [email release];


    }
    CFRelease(mulEmail) ;


}
[array release];
CFRelease(addressBook);


[pool release];
```

Comment: thx, are there no such attributes as time when entry was created ?

Comment: see ABPerson 's kABPersonCreationDateProperty
& kABPersonModificationDateProperty

Comment: Many keys used in this answer do not exist anymore starting iOS 10.

Answer (score 0):

Default attributes for a Person: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/addressbook/address_book_objective_c_constants/default_person_properties

> **kABFirstNameProperty**: First name.
>
> **kABLastNameProperty**: Last name.
>
> **kABFirstNamePhoneticProperty**: Phonetic representation of the first name.
>
> **kABLastNamePhoneticProperty**: Phonetic representation of the last name.
>
> **kABNicknameProperty**: Nickname.
>
> **kABMaidenNameProperty**: Maiden name.
>
> **kABBirthdayProperty**: Birth date.
>
> **kABBirthdayComponentsProperty**: Birth date as date components.
>
> **kABOrganizationProperty**: Company name.
>
> **kABJobTitleProperty**: Job title.
>
> **kABHomePageProperty**: Home web page.
>
> **kABURLsProperty**: Web pages.
>
> **kABCalendarURIsProperty**: Calendar URIs.
>
> **kABEmailProperty**: Email addresses.
>
> **kABAddressProperty**: Street addresses.
>
> **kABOtherDatesProperty**: Dates associated with a person.
>
> **kABOtherDateComponentsProperty**: Dates associated with a person, as date components.
>
> **kABRelatedNamesProperty**: Names of people related to a person.
>
> **kABDepartmentProperty**: Department name.
>
> **kABPersonFlags**: Property that specifies the name ordering and configuration of a record in the Address Book application. See [Person Flags](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/addressbook/abperson/person_flags).
>
> **kABPhoneProperty**: Generic phone number.
>
> **kABInstantMessageProperty**: Instant messaging ID.
>
> **kABNoteProperty**: Notes.
>
> **kABSocialProfileProperty**: Social network profile.
>
> **kABMiddleNameProperty**: Middle name.
>
> **kABMiddleNamePhoneticProperty**: Phonetic representation of the middle name.
>
> **kABTitleProperty**: Title, such as “Mr.,” “Mrs.,” “General,” “Cardinal,” or “Lord.”
>
> **kABSuffixProperty**: Suffix, such as “Sr.,” “Jr.,” “III.,” or “Esq.”

And because a Person is a Record, it also has: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/addressbook/address_book_objective_c_constants/default_record_properties

> **kABUIDProperty**: The unique ID for this record. It’s guaranteed never to change, no matter how much the record changes. If you need to store a reference to a record, use this value.
>
> **kABCreationDateProperty**: The date when the record was first saved.
>
> **kABModificationDateProperty**: The date when the record was last saved.

Note, the [`properties()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/addressbook/abperson/1458494-properties) should return you the list of all properties of a Person.